# How to find and replace case sensitive whole words in python

Tags: python, regex, replace

Consider the below mcve:

```
import re
import textwrap

import traceback
import unittest


def replace_words(content, replacements):
    rc = re.compile(r"[A-Za-z_]\w*")

    def translate(match):
        word = match.group(0)
        return replacements.get(word, word)
    return rc.sub(translate, content, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)


class class_name(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.replacements = [
            {
                'PLUS': '"+"',
                'DASH': '"-"',
                'BANG': '"!"',
                'TILDE': '"~"',
                'STAR': '"*"',
                'SLASH': '"/"',
                'PERCENT': '"%"',
                'LEFT_PAREN': '"("',
                'RIGHT_PAREN': '")"'
            }, {
                "IF": "fi",
                "FOO": "oof",
                "BAR": "rab",
                "OP_FOO": "oof_op"
            }
        ]
        self.texts = [
            textwrap.dedent("""\
                variable_identifier :
                    IDENTIFIER
                primary_expression :
                    foo1
                    foo2
                    foo3
                    LEFT_PAREN expression RIGHT_PAREN
                unary_operator :
                    PLUS
                    DASH
                    BANG
                    TILDE
                multiplicative_expression :
                    unary_expression
                    multiplicative_expression STAR unary_expression
                    multiplicative_expression SLASH unary_expression
                    multiplicative_expression PERCENT unary_expression\
            """),
            textwrap.dedent("""\
                IF identifier IDENTIFIER FOO BAR BARycentric
                OP_FOO
            """)
        ]
        self.expected_results = [
            textwrap.dedent("""\
                variable_identifier :
                    IDENTIFIER
                primary_expression :
                    foo1
                    foo2
                    foo3
                    "(" expression ")"
                unary_operator :
                    "+"
                    "-"
                    "!"
                    "~"
                multiplicative_expression :
                    unary_expression
                    multiplicative_expression "*" unary_expression
                    multiplicative_expression "/" unary_expression
                    multiplicative_expression "%" unary_expression\
            """),
            textwrap.dedent("""\
                fi identifier IDENTIFIER oof rab BARycentric
                oof_op
            """)
        ]

    def _tester(self, f):
        replacements = self.replacements
        expected_results = self.expected_results
        texts = self.texts
        self.assertEqual(f(texts[0], replacements[0]), expected_results[0])
        self.assertEqual(f(texts[1], replacements[1]), expected_results[1])

    def test_replace_words(self):
        self._tester(replace_words)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

`replace_words` function is attempting to search and replace case sensitive whole words in a given text using a dictionary of replacements above code but it will fail in the line `self.assertEqual(f(texts[0], replacements[0]), expected_results[0])` though and I don't know why.

So the question would be, how do you find and replace case sensitive whole words using a replacements dictionary in python?

Comment: Your input that you are using to "test" the solutions is no longer posted. Please remember to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The answer is "buggy" only when you attempt to test it on much different input, after it was posted, without clearly specifying all your criteria first. Again, when posting, ensure that the proper mcve is applied first. As it currently stands, my answer below returns the desired output. Correct me if I an wrong about the output, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` and `re.findall`:

```
import re
def regex_string(d, to_lower = False):
   if not to_lower: 
     return '|'.join(r'\b{}\b'.format(i) for i in d.keys())
   return '|'.join([c for b in [[r'\b{}\b'.format(i.lower()), r'\b{}\b'.format(i)] for i in d.keys()] for c in b])

replacements = {
    'PLUS': '"+"',
    'DASH': '"-"',
    'BANG': '"!"',
    'TILDE': '"~"',
    'STAR': '"*"',
    'SLASH': '"/"',
    'PERCENT': '"%"',
    'LEFT_PAREN': '"("',
    'RIGHT_PAREN': '")"'
}
replaced = re.sub(regex_string(replacements, True), '{}', content)
final_result = replaced.format(*[replacements.get(i, i) for i in re.findall(regex_string(replacements, True), content)])
```

Output (`case 1`):

```
variable_identifier :
IDENTIFIER
primary_expression :
   foo1
   foo2
   foo3
   "(" expression ")"
unary_operator :
   "+"
   "-"
   "!"
   "~"
multiplicative_expression :
   unary_expression
   multiplicative_expression "*" unary_expression
   multiplicative_expression "/" unary_expression
   multiplicative_expression "%" unary_expression
```

Output (`case 2`):

```
fi identifier IDENTIFIER oof rab BARycentric
oof_op
```

Or, even shorter:

```
replaced = re.sub(regex_string(replacements, True), lambda x:replacements.get(x.group(), x.group()), content)
```